# Getting data from angular js resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

I got the resource of the following format
.

```
d {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false}
$promise: Promise
$$state: Object
__proto__: Object
$resolved: true
result: Array[2]
0: Object
caption: "test"
created_at: "2016-01-13 07:51:09"
description: " wow"
ending_pound: "19"
id: "220"
is_active: "2"
name: "Arsenal cake"
path: "thumb_167926cake.jpg"
price: "1000.00"
starting_pound: "1"
updated_at: "2016-01-13 07:51:09"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: d
```

From which i need to extract result only.

I got the response from the following

```
.factory('urgent_cake', function($resource) {
  return $resource('api/urgent-cake');
})

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, urgent_cake){
          urgent_cakes_collection= urgent_cake.get();
```

**How can i get results only from above object**

### EDIT

when i try

```
.query()
```

It gives following error

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] query
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object&p2=GET&p3=api%2Furgent-cake
    at ionic.bundle.js:13380
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using angular factories in a wrong way.
If you don't need a custom constructor logic, you should prefer service.

So:

```
module.service('Cake', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/cake');
}
```

Inside your controller:

```
module.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, Cake){
    Cake.query({ }, function(cakes) {
        $scope.cakes = cakes;
    });
});
```